# Android Studio emulator snapshot error

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have problem with emulator in Android Studio it looks like this:

[image]

I have read that i must turn off starting by snapshot and I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First time you create an Emulator you will see this message. If you will close the emulator, the next time you run the Emulator you won't see this message. If this happens the next time you start the emulator, I suggest that you delete the old emulator(s) and start an clean new one. p.s. Make sure you upgraded the HAXM as well.